# Changing Mac OS user password programmatically using C++

Tags: c++, macos

I'm trying to change local user password on MacOS Catalina using C++. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNTESTED:
If you're running with permissions to do so, you can use

```cpp
system("security set-keychain-password -o oldpassword -p newpassword /Users/username/Library/Keychains/login.keychain");
```